# How to get the number of pymongo active threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, pymongo

I have a multi thread program that uses pymongo in main program and each thread. Since pymongo will create 2 threads for each connection, how can I find that the number of threads created by pymongo?

```
threading.activeCount()
```

I can get total active threads with above command but I don't know how much belong to pymongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command in MongoDB shell: `db.serverStatus()`.

It gives the server status including connections. You can use it with `pymongo` in your Python code:

```
con = db.command("serverStatus")["connections"];
Current_con = con["current"] #Int Value.
```

Note `con` is a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

PyMongo does not create two threads per connection. Each MongoClient has a single background thread for periodic cleanup tasks, as well as a background thread per server for monitoring the status of your MongoDB servers. So if you create the default MongoClient it connects to one server on localhost:27017, spawning a total of two threads:

```
c = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")
```

If you do this:

```
c = MongoClient("mongodb://host1,host2/?replicaSet=my_replica_set")
```

Then PyMongo will discover replica set members and spawn threads to monitor them until it has discovered the whole set. So, if you have a three-member set, PyMongo spawns four threads.

Short answer, to know the number of threads PyMongo has started, then you should periodically execute this:

```
len(c.nodes) + 1
```

That is the number of servers PyMongo knows of, plus one for the cleanup thread.

[A brief explanation is here, where the FAQ says "MongoClient spawns multiple threads to run background tasks such as monitoring connected servers."](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#is-pymongo-fork-safe) I also wrote a [very thorough explanation of PyMongo's use of threads here](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/developer/periodic_executor.html), intended mainly for future PyMongo maintainers.